# Static variables used from lambdas are not initialized

Tags: c++, regex, lambda

I am trying to use a static variable in a lambda like this

```
void scrape_link(const std::string& url, std:function<void()> callback)
{
    static const std::regex link_match { 
        R"re(href="([^"]+)")re",
        std::regex_constants::optimize
    };

    async_download(url,[callback=std::move(callback)] (std::vector<char>& data)
    {
        std::smatch matches;
        if(std::regex_search(data.begin(), data.end(), matches, link_match))
            std::cout << matches[1] << std::endl;
        callback();
    });
}
```

When i compile this code without `-O3` flag I don't seem to face any issues. It works as expected. But with the flag turned on, the regex search fails everytime. I'm suspecting the `link_match` object is not being initialized properly. Any idea how to fix this?

Note that the lambda is called asyncronously from a different thread.

Update: It seems like it was a compiler issue. I was compiling this on gcc 6.2. I am not observing this issue in gcc 7.2.

Comment: _"I'm suspecting the link_match object is not being initialized properly..."_ can you put a breakpoint in and check?

Comment: It seems to be initialized properly when im debugging, but the regex search still fails.

Comment: Does it fail with flag `-O3` and without `std::optimize`?

Comment: yes, even without the std::optimize flag it fails.

Comment: Try it with `-O2` so we can narrow it down to the `GCC` flags, what would be the result?

Comment: -O2 seems to work fine. I think its probably a bug with my compiler gcc 6.2.

Comment: Could you move the link_match definition into the lambda body?

Comment: To get to the bottom of it you can try `-O2` and then add `-O3` flags manually one by one from [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html) and then see which is causing the failure. I would be interested to know.

Comment: This is definitely a compiler issue. I just upgraded to gcc 7.2 and the issue is gone completely.

Comment: Please mention the `GCC` version that the issue was reproduced in your question for later reference.

Comment: You are not explicitly capturing link_match, which could be an issue.  I suspect the optimizer skips the initialization of link_match, since it it not used within the function. You should try that.  It could still be a compiler bug, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first glance, this seems like a compiler bug.  `link_match` is not used within its immediate scope, which may confuse the optimizer. Here's a workaround:

```
void scrape_link(const std::string& url, std:function<void()> callback)
{
    static const std::regex link_match { 
        R"re(href="([^"]+)")re",
        std::regex_constants::optimize
    };

    // force the creation of link_match by using it in the capture clause.

    async_download(url,[&link_match, callback=std::move(callback)] (std::vector<char>& data)
    {
        std::smatch matches;
        if(std::regex_search(data.begin(), data.end(), matches, link_match))
            std::cout << matches[1] << std::endl;
        callback();
    });
}
```

Comment: This is a good point and I guess will solve the problem on `GCC v6.2` (@user1353535 can confirm). However, it is still a compiler bug since it is a valid code to not pass the static object as part of the capture of lambda.

Comment: Yes.  The good news is that OP reported that gcc 7.2 doesn't exhibit the same behaviour.